# c# multiple try and catch for textbox values

Tags: c#, try-catch

i'm trying to group try and catch in one for 6 textboxes values. In class i have described similar 6 methods:

```
public void Setpajamos(int newValue)
{
    if (newValue >= 0 && newValue <= 30)
        pajamos = newValue;
    else
        throw new Exception("Patikrinkite duomenis");
}
```

In main Form i have try and catch code:

```
try
{
    BustoKreditas.Setvaikusk(newvaikusk);
    BustoKreditas.Setpajamos(newpajamos);
    BustoKreditas.Setisipareigojimai(newisipareigojimai);
    BustoKreditas.SetPaskolosSuma(newpaskolosSuma);
    BustoKreditas.Setlaikotarpis(newlaikotarpis);
    BustoKreditas.Setpastatoamzius(newpastatoamzius);

}
catch 
{
    MessageBox.Show("value to big");    
}
```

The thing is that try and catch works on first textbox only. For all others i can put whatever number i want and it do not show any message.

Comment: Put the try/catch in the `SetXXX` methods.

Comment: Have you checked if they do actually throw an exception - step into each method & see what it does. If you have set all values out of range - then only the first value will show an exception. No attempt will be made to set subsequent values.

Comment: Hi, each standalone method throws exception, but do not when all in the row.

Comment: If you are wanting to check each of the values then you cannot combine all calls in one catch. Once the first method has thrown an exception the code will continue after the catch statement - it will not continue to the next line of code.

Comment: Can i do try/catch for each method separately? If so, how to get diferent messages for each exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to collect all the errors together.
(In your code, the first exception will cause the code to jump to your `catch`, therefore not calling any of the other methods.)

In which case you could try something like this:

```
public void Setpajamos(int newValue, List<string> errors)
{
   if (newValue >= 0 && newValue <= 30)
   {
      pajamos = newValue;
   }
   else
   {
      errors.Add("Patikrinkite duomenis");
   }
}
```

In your main form:

```
var errors = new List<string>()
BustoKreditas.Setvaikusk(newvaikusk, errors);
BustoKreditas.Setpajamos(newpajamos, errors);
BustoKreditas.Setisipareigojimai(newisipareigojimai, errors);
BustoKreditas.SetPaskolosSuma(newpaskolosSuma, errors);
BustoKreditas.Setlaikotarpis(newlaikotarpis, errors);
BustoKreditas.Setpastatoamzius(newpastatoamzius, errors);
if (errors.Count > 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors));
}
```